# Eliminar campos vacios de un objeto usando reduce de forma dinámica JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce

me he encontrado con un caso en el cual tengo un objeto con varios ramas, el tema es que quiero eliminar los campos que se encuentren vacios sin usar delete ya que me muta el objeto original, quisiera consultar de su conocimiento para saber cual es la mejor manera de implementarlo con un reduce, comparto el objeto

```
const objetoActual = {
    requerimiento: {
        datoUsuario: {
            nombre: "Andres",
            segundoNombre: "",
            apellido: "villa",
            segundoApellido: ""
        },
        infoContacto:{
            tel:"",
            correo:"correo",
            direccion:""
        }
    }
}

const objetoConReduce = {
    requerimiento: {
        datoUsuario: {
            nombre: "Andres",
            apellido: "villa",
        },
        infoContacto:{
            correo:"correo",
        }
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Encontré este método, pero no sé en rendimiento si es la mejor opcíon, en caso de existir otra opción estaré agradecido

```
const removeEmpty = (obj) =>
  Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(k => obj[k] !== null && obj[k] !== undefined)  // Remove undef. and null.
    .reduce((newObj, k) =>
      typeof obj[k] === 'object' ?
        Object.assign(newObj, {[k]: removeEmpty(obj[k])}) :  // Recurse.
        Object.assign(newObj, {[k]: obj[k]}),  // Copy value.
      {});
```